# SSRS Subscription Error - Error writing file

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have just started experiencing an error with my File Share subscriptions. The log file tells me the following:

```
    subscription!WindowsService_68!1da4!06/01/2011-15:00:06:: i INFO: Error writing file Next Day 2011_06_01_150006.xls to path \\server\share$\folder
```

There is nothing more in the log that gives me any clues as to why it is failing.

I have made sure that the execution account and the user account has access to the share with full permissions and ensured that the file path is exactly correct.

Any further ideas guys?

Comment: Anything significant about the fact that it's a new month? Is there a missing folder for June?

Comment: It always writes to the same foler...

Comment: I'd test whether you can write any file to that folder from any source. If that works, try writing a simple file from the same source. Then try an Excel file. Just trying to break it down into tiny steps here.

Comment: And you read this[Troubleshooting Subscriptions: Part II, Using the Reporting Services Trace Log File](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deanka/archive/2010/02/16/troubleshooting-subscriptions-part-ii-using-the-report-services-trace-log-file.aspx)?

Comment: We cant write to any files under this shar but can write the same report to a different share, it must be a permissions thing but i just cant tell where... The log file's `Error writing file` doesnt exactly help

Answer (score 3):

SSRS report subscriptions must have valid owners otherwise they error out.  We recently had a DBA quit and started getting this error.  Fixing the subscriptions was achieved by the following blog on MSDN [Change Subscription owner](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/07/10/tip-change-the-owner-of-report-server-subscription.aspx)

**Edit:**

Link to answer was deleted, here it is in all it's glory:

https://web.archive.org/web/20190203054104/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/miah/2008/07/10/tip-change-the-owner-of-sql-reporting-services-subscription/